# Building Pandas tables of where and for what values maxima are found

Tags: python, pandas

I have `pandas` data with the structure reported by `info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 7058 entries, 0 to 7057
Data columns (total 16 columns):
ID              7058 non-null int64
Description     7058 non-null object
Calories        7057 non-null float64
Protein         7057 non-null float64
TotalFat        7057 non-null float64
Carbohydrate    7057 non-null float64
Sodium          6974 non-null float64
SaturatedFat    6757 non-null float64
Cholesterol     6770 non-null float64
Sugar           5148 non-null float64
Calcium         6922 non-null float64
Iron            6935 non-null float64
Potassium       6649 non-null float64
VitaminC        6726 non-null float64
VitaminE        4338 non-null float64
VitaminD        4224 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(14), int64(1), object(1)
```

and I would like to produce a table of the Descriptions and values corresponding to each of the maximum values for the numeric columns along the lines of

```
Description       Value     Category
SALT, TABLE       38758.00  Sodium
FAT,BEEF TALLOW   100.00    TotalFat
FRUCTOSE,DRY,PDR  100.00    Carbohydrate
...
```

I can get a bits and pieces of this with things like

```
>>> usda.Description[usda[['Protein','TotalFat','Sodium','Carbohydrate']].idxmax()]

4660    SOY PROT ISOLATE,K TYPE,CRUDE PROT BASIS
288                              FAT,BEEF TALLOW
264                                   SALT,TABLE
6959        SWEETENERS,TABLETOP,FRUCTOSE,DRY,PDR
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

and

```
>>> usda[['Protein','TotalFat','Sodium','Carbohydrate']].max()

Protein            88.32
TotalFat          100.00
Sodium          38758.00
Carbohydrate      100.00
dtype: float64
```

but that's about as far as I can mange.

Is there a compact way to get find the maximum value for each numeric column in my dataset and produce a table with that value, the corresponding 'Description' and the name of the column for which the maximum was found?

Answer (score 0):

starting with:

```
  Description  Sodium  TotalFat  Carbohydrate
0         ABC       1        10             4
1         DEF       2         9             5
2         GHI       3         8             0

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

you can melt the categories:

```
>>> mlt = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Description',
...               value_vars=['Sodium', 'TotalFat', 'Carbohydrate'],
...               value_name='value', var_name='category')
>>> mlt  
  Description      category  value
0         ABC        Sodium      1
1         DEF        Sodium      2
2         GHI        Sodium      3
3         ABC      TotalFat     10
4         DEF      TotalFat      9
5         GHI      TotalFat      8
6         ABC  Carbohydrate      4
7         DEF  Carbohydrate      5
8         GHI  Carbohydrate      0

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

and then group by the categories:

```
>>> mdf = mlt.groupby('category').apply(lambda obj: obj.loc[obj.value.idxmax()])
>>> mdf.reset_index(drop=True)
  Description      category  value
0         DEF  Carbohydrate      5
1         GHI        Sodium      3
2         ABC      TotalFat     10

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```